# when deploying stack using sam deploy this is the error i am getting

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, serverless

when using sam deploy
after the jenkins pipeline is started , it builds the code , and when the sam deploy is triggered , this is the error i am getting, the changeset in cloudformation is created and is in create_in_progress state

```
Waiting for changeset to be created..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 313, in wait_for_changeset
    waiter.wait(ChangeSetName=changeset_id, StackName=stack_name, WaiterConfig=waiter_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 55, in wait
    Waiter.wait(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 388, in wait
    raise WaiterError(
botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Max attempts exceeded

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/cli_validation/image_repository_validation.py", line 92, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 176, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 126, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 86, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/commands/_utils/cdk_support_decorators.py", line 38, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 192, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/command.py", line 359, in do_cli
    deploy_context.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 166, in run
    return self.deploy(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/commands/deploy/deploy_context.py", line 249, in deploy
    result, changeset_type = self.deployer.create_and_wait_for_changeset(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 528, in create_and_wait_for_changeset
    self.wait_for_changeset(result["Id"], stack_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 318, in wait_for_changeset
    reason = resp["StatusReason"]
KeyError: 'StatusReason'
```

this is the error message i am getting
i used sam_cli_poll_delay = 60 , but this is taking more than 25 minutes to deploy , i am using 1.76.0 is the sam cli and 2.4.21 is the awscli version in use , and using AWS SAM